# What are these circular basket-like structures on a high voltage transformer's insulators?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, power-engineering, power-grid

Wikimedia commons contains this public-domain image of a high-voltage transformer of the Tarza power plant in Iraq, [taken by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:High-voltage_in_Iraq.jpg) Marvin Daniels in the U.S. Army:

[image: A Siemens HV transformer]

There is much I do not immediately understand about the design of the transformer from this. I presume, perhaps naïvely, that:

1. The three large insulators coming out (just above the Siemens brand name) are the three phases.
2. This is the first "transmission" transformer seen after the generator, and converts high current, medium voltage (~10-30 kV) from the generator to lower current, HV for transmission (~115 kV to 765 kV-ish).

I don't quite understand:

1. What's the point of the "inverted hanging baskets" just visible at the top of the frame? They look like they're designed to shape an E field, but the three large insulators don't have them — and the distance between them and the next metal structure looks (perhaps deceivingly) closer.
2. Are the three "pipes" seen coming over the top of the firewall likely to be the "input" conductors to the other side of the transformer?
3. What's the big, ominous red strap going to the ground — *is* it a ground?

Obviously, I've never seen a transformer this beefy in reality. Power electronics is a very alien, very lethal world of engineering away from my skills — but clearly a lot of engineering has gone into this transformer, and I'd love a detailed description of exactly why it looks like it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These "pipes" are part of a GIS busbar system. There are cables connected to these on the other side of that wall. This saves a lot of space compared to the larger bushings used on the other side (the ones you call insulators).

[image]

Source: https://library.e.abb.com/public/fdb27bc89bf946138a151d51335bac6e/7%20Hitachi_Energy_145kV_Dry_Plug-in_GIS_Transformer_Termination.pdf?x-sign=V/4bnoBI7Oqa97k2sxhYyJKu99LywWl/JKCcAu+/PVMBIlnVsPy9SJVblhiIxhU+

--

[image]

---

The grading rings are, as vir states, placed on the surge arrestors to create a more uniform electric field during a surge (lightning flash or similar) and prevent breakdown. They are not needed on the transformer bushings because a surge won't reach the bushings. The surge arrestors will already have led the current to earth.

The bushings could have had corona rings. Those look similar but are not used for the same purpose.

---

I'm 99% certain that **the red thing *is* actually earth.**

"But earth is *always* yellow and green, and this is red." And it terminates above ground in small cables.

Have a look at this picture I've taken myself during commissioning of a 420 kV transformer:

[image]

Notice that the size is the same as in your image, the black insulators behind, the color, and it's terminated above ground. It is, or will be, connected to earth somewhere.

---

The part where the Siemens brand hangs is the heat exchanger with fans. I don't know what the thing in the background is, but it's not part of the transformer.

---

Below are some more pictures I've taken myself.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight and wonderful pictures! What does GIS stand for (gas insulated switchgear?), and why _is_ earth a mixture of conventional green & yellow and red (=danger?)

Comment: Yes, it's gas insulated switchgear. Conventionally they're filled with SF6 gas, but that's very bad for the climate so they are moving away from it, slowly. The earth will be coated in green and yellow when the installation is finished. The red is simply the color of the bar underneath the green and yellow coating.

Answer (score 7):

The rings around the insulators are *grading rings*, and are similar to corona rings but they even out the electric field gradient around the insulator to help prevent breakdown.

Comment: Apologies, but I downvoted this since all but the first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: No apologies necessary!  Thank you for correcting me!  I have deleted the incorrect portions of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

HV insluators are ineffective without the corona/grading rings as the voltage gradient tends to build up around the "live" side of the insulator, resulting in an early breakdown.

The ring tends to push the E-field gradient outside of the ring, protecting the insulator.

Take a look at what happens to the electric field along the insulator when you add the ring:
[image]

<sub>Image from [this article](https://www.slideshare.net/sampengalavenkatesh/52introduction-effects-of-corona-ring-design-by-electric-field-intensity-using-3dcoulomb)</sub>

The three insulators in your picture don't have the rings presumably because the voltage they have to withstand is lower.

Comment: There is also a triple junction between the air insulator and the conductor.